# Git clone/pull across local network

Tags: networking, git, version-control, ubuntu-12.10

I'm trying to clone/pull a repository in another PC using Ubuntu Quantal. I have done this on Windows before but I don't know what is the problem on ubuntu. I tried these:

```
git clone file:////pc-name/repo/repository.git
git clone file:////192.168.100.18/repo/repository.git
git clone file:////user:pass@pc-name/repo/repository.git
git clone smb://c-pc/repo/repository.git
git clone //192.168.100.18/repo/repository.git
```

Always I got:

```
Cloning into 'intranet'...
fatal: '//c-pc/repo/repository.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

or

```
fatal: repository '//192.168.100.18/repo/repository.git' does not exist
```

More:

- The other PC has username and password
- Is not networking issue, I can access and ping it.
- I just installed git doing `apt-get install git` (dependencies installed)
- I'm running git from the terminal (I'm not using git-shell)

What is causing this and how to fix this? Any help would be great!

#### UPDATE

I have cloned the repo on Windows using `git clone //192.168.100.18/repo/intranet.git` without problems. So, the repo is accessible and exist! Maybe the problem is due user credentials?

Comment: I'm not really sure if this question belong here, but I have seen similar questions on SF

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It depends on how you have your server configured to serve content.

If over ssh:

```
git clone user@192.168.100.18:repo/repository.git
```

or if a webserver is providing the content (http or https)

```
https://user@192.168.100.18/repo/repository.git
```

or if available via a file path:

```
git clone file://path/to/repo
```

or if the server is running the git daemon:

```
git clone git://192.168.100.18/repo
```

Comment: On Windows, I'm cloning using `git clone //192.168.100.18/repo/repository.git`, but I logged previously on the `192.168.100.18` maching, so this is the `file://` way?

Comment: useful answer, thanks! To clone a repo located at a Windows shared folder I used `git clone file://\\\PC1\path-to-repo-dir`

Comment: @IvanFerrerVilla almost, the actual path is: `file:///\\PC1\path-to-repo-dir`

Comment: @MiklX and how would you include a username and password?

Answer (score 16):

The manual for `git-clone` says:

```
Git natively supports ssh, git, http, https, ftp, ftps, and rsync protocols
```

Note that SMB is not in the list.

When running `git` on Windows, the `//host/path` syntax works because the OS supports it natively - SMB remote paths can be used anywhere a local path can be used. That is not the case in unix, where SMB is an alien thing, and `//` is equivalent to `/` in the pathname resolution algorithm.

mount the remote filesystem, then you will have the ability to refer to it with a unix-style pathname that `git` (and every other tool on the system) understands.

For information on mounting smbfs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/137011/how-to-mount-a-samba-shared-folder-ubuntu-x-ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

This issue seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200181/how-to-git-clone-a-repo-in-windows-from-other-pc-within-the-lan.  Perhaps the administrative share helps alleviate the problem (e.g. //pc-name/c$/path/to/repo)

Comment: no, is the same case, but not the same problem, I read that thread before :/ and the repo directory is shared correctly